# Rails Routing global Account id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My rails application is based on accounts. So every user belongs to an account, every project and so on.

Currently I got routes like:

```
/mission-control
/tasks
/projects
```

And I'm getting the current account by the user. Since a user should be able to have permissions to many accounts I'd like to have the following routes:

```
/:account_id/mission-control
/:account_id/tasks
/:account_id/projects
```

I know I could write:

```
resource :accounts do
  resource :tasks
end
```

but this would end up in e.g.

```
/accounts/1/tasks
```

Hope somebody could help me how to write routes for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got the correct way:

At first I needed to define the scope like:

```
scope ":account_id" do
  resources :tasks
  resources :projects
end
```

Then, to make eversthing work, cause links within a loop like:

```
<%= link_to "Project", project %>
```

won't work, you need to set default url options in the application controller:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  if @current_account.present?
    { :account_id => @current_account.id }
  else
    { :account_id => nil }
  end
end
```

That fixes every `No Route Matches Error` for me. If there is no :account_id there will be no error, e.g. for that devise stuff.

For @Mohamad:

```
before_filter :set_current_account  

# current account
def set_current_account
  # get account by scoped :account_id

  if params[:account_id]
    @current_account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    return @current_account
  end

  # dont' raise the exception if we are in that devise stuff
  if !devise_controller?
    raise "Account not found."
  end
end
```

That devise and error handling could be better tho. :S

Comment: How are you pulling the `@current_account`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a scope like this:

```
scope ":account_id" do
  resources :tasks
  resources :projects
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But using a scope like you suggested and going to `/1/tasks` the app tries to render the show action like it would do on `/tasks/1` :/

Comment: Try with `resources` instead.. I copy pasted your example but it wasn't pluralized

Comment: I updated my routes as you suggested and it works fine untill I'm rendering a partial like: `<%= render "tasks/index_item", :task => task %>`. I'm getting a `No route matches`-Error for `task` within that partial :/

Comment: I know it has something to do with the `:task => task` but I don't know where the problem should be

Comment: That is another problem in itself and has nothing to do with your routes. Are you trying to render multiple tasks?

Comment: Yep, I do. I got this `<%= render ...` within a loop.

Comment: Assuming you have a file called `app/views/tasks/_index_item.html.erb` Try this instead: `<%= render partial: 'tasks/index_item', collection: @tasks, as: :task %>`